# I Want to create a application which display list of installed application with help of android service

Tags: android-service

I Want to create a application which display list of installed application with help of android service.

**Which android service to use in this scenario?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want, you can use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics) , it runs synchronously in the background, and it is very flexible, espcially if you want to schedule your work. You can also use [Foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) if you want to show a notification while your app is running. You can use [Bound Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services) if you want to exchange data between an activty and the service.

Before android Oreo, you could use[Intent Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService#:%7E:text=IntentService%20is%20a%20base%20class,it%20runs%20out%20of%20work.), but starting from Oreo, it started to cause an exception. You can also still use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) but it has serveral drawbacks and `AsyncTask` may be deprecated in the future.

This is an overview, you haven't mentioned specific details about your app, hope this overview will help choose which way you go.